# Want to Store data from CSV into Array using Open CSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a CSV file which contains `Customer Order Details` in the format:

```
OrderID  Name Status
```

I want to store `Order ID` and `Status` in `String[][]`.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
String nextLine;    
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) 
{
    System.out.println(nextLine[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class OpenCSVReader {
    private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "./users.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
        ) {
            // Reading Records One by One in a String array
            String[] nextRecord;
            while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Name : " + nextRecord[0]);
                System.out.println("Email : " + nextRecord[1]);
                System.out.println("Phone : " + nextRecord[2]);
                System.out.println("Country : " + nextRecord[3]);
                System.out.println("==========================");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here value is hardcoded, how to Initialize array without dimension and store data into that

Comment: You can use List instead

Comment: How, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Example using List:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;


public class ParseFullCSVExample
{
   @SuppressWarnings("resource")
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      //Build reader instance
      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"), ',', '"', 1);

      //Read all rows at once
      List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();

      for(String[] row : allRows){
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
      }
   }
}
```